# L3 Etherchannel cost calculation

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, ospf, etherchannel

Q1: I have read that in layer 2, if any of the links of a portchannel goes down,the cost of the portchannel is recalculated. Does that apply to L3 portchannel also?

If so, assume I am running OSPF in a port channel environment, and one of the links of the portchannel goes down, will the SPF be recomputed?

Q2: Why at all the cost recalculation take place in layer 2 portchannel when the link goes down? I mean, STP treats the entire port channel as a single link, so why the reconvergence happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tag this with a vendor, but you use the Cisco term, "portchannel," so I assume you mean this as a Cisco question.

> Q1: I have read that in layer 2, if any of the links of a portchannel
>   goes down,the cost of the portchannel is recalculated. Does that apply
>   to L3 portchannel also?

Yes, the link gets a new layer-3 cost if the routing protocol dynamically calculates this. For instance RIP would not change the metric, but OSPF would change the metric.

> If so, assume I am running OSPF in a port channel environment, and one
>   of the links of the portchannel goes down, will the SPF be recomputed?

Yes, OSPF will change the metric and the routers in an area would all rerun the SPF algorithm.

> Q2: Why at all the cost recalculation take place in layer 2
>   portchannel when the link goes down? I mean, STP treats the entire port
>   channel as a single link, so why the reconvergence happens?

It does this because that link may no longer be the preferred link; the bandwidth of the link has changed.